# T-Mobile WWAN IP address is DoD Network Information Center?

Tags: mobile, ip, ios, iphone

I wrote an app that grabs the IP address of my Wifi as well as the WWAN i.e. the data part of my Tmobile plan. I have an iPhone. Here is what my app prints. I use pretty standard code to obtain the WWAN address.

```
addresses: {
"lo0/ipv4" = "127.0.0.1";
"lo0/ipv6" = "fe80::1";
"pdp_ip0/ipv4" = "21.29.91.173"; <---- WWAN
}
```

Does anybody know if this is a fluke or is Tmobile in cahoots with the US Department of Defense?

Here's a traceroute after I tethered my laptop to the phone:

```
traceroute to google.com (173.194.79.102), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  172.20.10.1 (172.20.10.1)  23.877 ms  2.199 ms  1.677 ms
 2  10.170.226.64 (10.170.226.64)  59.335 ms  81.022 ms  53.504 ms
 3  10.170.214.11 (10.170.214.11)  27.970 ms  38.150 ms  39.914 ms
 4  10.164.162.198 (10.164.162.198)  43.886 ms  37.796 ms  57.084 ms
 5  10.164.165.27 (10.164.165.27)  42.297 ms  30.223 ms  38.536 ms
 6  74.125.48.22 (74.125.48.22)  44.485 ms  34.160 ms  39.997 ms
 7  209.85.249.5 (209.85.249.5)  56.696 ms  73.682 ms  39.855 ms
 8  209.85.249.63 (209.85.249.63)  40.396 ms
    209.85.246.38 (209.85.246.38)  41.527 ms  75.153 ms
 9  72.14.232.63 (72.14.232.63)  74.623 ms  306.078 ms  52.121 ms
10  216.239.40.144 (216.239.40.144)  51.889 ms
    74.125.37.208 (74.125.37.208)  614.784 ms  198.198 ms
11  209.85.143.71 (209.85.143.71)  53.930 ms  827.998 ms
    216.239.46.175 (216.239.46.175)  196.352 ms
12  * * *
13  pb-in-f102.1e100.net (173.194.79.102)  59.873 ms  51.148 ms  49.870 ms
```

172.16.0.0/12 = private block

74.125.0.0/16 = google

209.85.128.0/17 = google

216.239.32.0/19 = google

Comment: Sir please remain calm while we send some officers to pick you up.

Answer (score 5):

Check the WWAN IP gained from a external site like visiting www.whatismyip.com from your iPhone.
Chances are that the carrier are doing a NAT444/CGN on your connection, but not obeying RFC 6598, but using live adresses as NAT adresses to avoid breaking customer's routers (which would happen if they would use RFC 1918 adresses).

If you get the DoD IP there, it might just be outdated WHOIS data for the IP in question, eg that the IP is no longer in DoD's ownership, but WHOIS hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: Yes, it's most likely just outdated WHOIS data.

Comment: It's 172.56.38.33 - T-Mobile USA In Hayward. How do I determine whether the DoD IP is a proxy?

Comment: If you would be proxied by DoD, the DoD IP would be visible on the OUTSIDE (eg on whatismyIP) and the T-mobile IP (172.56.38.33) on the INSIDE. Now its the opposite way around, and the most common case for this, is your operator (T-Mobile) not obeying RFC 6598 and using live IP's for NAT:ing their customers to prevent IPv4 exhaustion. Why they selected DoD IPs might be that they just randomed a IP network up to use as NAT and "hope it not being used anywhere else on the internet.".

Comment: Right but what if Tmobile has set it up like this: Phone---DoD---Tmo. Is that possible?

Comment: yes, but then you would not see DoD at all in the chain. As I said, its more likely the operator has configured a NAT to "misuse" the DoDs public IP space as "private IP". Think the 21.29.91.173 IP as a 192.168.x.x IP. And you would of course never connect directly to DoD, because that would incur huge security & abuse risks since anyone could then connect to DoD and masquerade as any T-mobile customer.

Comment: I tethered my laptop to the phone, and ran traceroute. The DoD IP is not in the chain FWIW.

Comment: The traceroute you did shows that apparently, they are assigning DoD IPs as endpoint IPs to their customers, while the route table is going through the gateway 172.20.10.1, which is a RFC 1918 range. This seems very odd to do, but the reason to do this, is that the operator is propably unaware of RFC 6598, and did a very dirty networking hack to prevent customer-owned routers configured for the 172.16.0.0/12-range to break.

Comment: Very odd. I may change to verizon in a couple days and if I do I'll recheck the situation. Thanks.